# Is cpu aware of which level(ring0 or ring3) that is running?

Tags: memory, windows-7, kernel, cpu, xen

I am working on xen hypervisor. Because of working below OS.The things I can see is physical devices such as cpu and memory.The Guest OS is HVM(windows 7).I need to copy it memory of kernel space(above 0x80000000).It works all right when copy below 0x80000000. But the win7 oops when I copy from above 0x80000000. I think the cpu is running on ring3 when I copy.But I need to know which level(ring0 or ring3) the vcpu of Guest OS is running on.(I use hvm_copy_from_guest_phys() in win7's context to do the copy operation)

Comment: CPU is aware of the ring it's in, yes. It has to be to know what permissions to enforce. Once your pages are set up, however, the only way to switch is by interrupts and system calls.